# Probability of 2 consecutive heads before a tails

Tags: probability

What's the probability of 2 consecutive heads before a tails, given that we keep flipping until we get either of these items? Is this approach correct?

Notation: P2h = probability of 2 consecutive heads; P1h = probability of 1 head

P2h = (1/2)*P1h

P1h = (1/2)

Thus, P2h = 1/4. **If this is correct, then why is it that P(2 heads in a row) == P(2 heads in a row before 1 tail)?**

Comment: Do you mean _precisely_ two consecutive heads, or do you mean _two or more_?  Also, how many coin tosses?

Comment: Well once we get two consecutive heads, it would be over; unlimited tosses, you keep flipping till you get either a tails or 2 consuecitve heads

Comment: Then consider the sample space of two fair coin tosses.

Comment: @AndrewChin Gotcha, so it would be 1/4. Any intuition as to why P(2 heads in a row) == P(2 heads in a row before 1 tail)?

Comment: I've written an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

\begin{array}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
\text{Coin 1} & \text{Coin 2} & \text{Probability}\\
\hline
\color{red}{T} & - & 0.50\\
H & \color{red}{T} & 0.25\\
H & H & \color{blue}{0.25}\\
\hline
\end{array}

In any trial with two events, the favourable outcome is called a *success* and the other is called a *failure*.  Intuitively, the probability of succeeding is exactly equal to the probability of succeeding before you fail, since you can only do one or the other.

Answer (score 0):

That is correct.

Notice,  Tossing a coin is a random experiment which can give either head or tail. When a fair coin is tossed the probability of getting either head or tail i.e. $\dfrac12$ remains constant from one toss to the next.

The probability of getting two successive heads is same as getting two heads before a tail comes before or between two successive heads.